# How to use ngoption to list all city for a state from the given JSON object

Tags: angularjs

```
$rootScope.STATES = [{state : 'Chhattisgarh',
                      city : ['Raipur', 'Bhilai', 'Bilaspur', 'Raigarh', 'Korba', 'Jagdalpur']},
                     {state : 'Orissa',
                      city : ['Anugul', 'Bhubaneshwar', 'Cuttack', 'Jharsuguda', 'Sambalpur', 'Rourkela']}];
```

I want to use only one selector group by states

Comment: what does your ui consist of - two select boxes?

Comment: Forget `ng-options` - if you had a variable `state` holding the desired state, how would you find the array of cities? With your data structure, you would need to go through the array of states and fine the appropriate object. Do that in the controller once and expose it on the scope, e.g. `$scope.selectedState`

Comment: I can get the list of cities and use that in ng-option but do we have any inbuilt method in angularjs to extract all cities from the above JSON object.

Answer (score -1):

One thing to note is that `ngModel` is required for `ngOptions` to work.

Check this http://plnkr.co/edit/sTs6LvtQMjofKikYKfyd?p=preview

Comment: I want to use only one select box with all city combined

Comment: What makes you think that the OP hasn't used `ng-model`?